# C program Vertical line not printing within window (Square)

Tags: c, window, ncurses

I currently have a program that simply draws a square to the screen,however, I'm trying to add vertical lines to this square, which does print to the screen, but not the the full length it is defined, and not within the square either. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    mvvline(1,1,ACS_VLINE,10); //does not fully print to screen, and is printed outside of the square
    refresh();

    WINDOW *win = newwin(10,10,0,0);
    box(win, '|', '-');
    touchwin(win);
    wrefresh(win);

    getchar();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you add your expected output?

Comment: The square is defined to start at the origin (0,0), the vertical line i'm drawing is defined to start at (1,1) so mathematically speaking.. the vertical line should be drawn in the square, but it's not, it's drawn right below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `mvwvline` instead of `mvvline`

```
mvwvline(win, 1, 1, '|', 10); // does print to screen
```

and of course you must move the code after the `win` varible is initialized

```
int main()
{
    initscr();
    refresh();

    WINDOW *win = newwin(10, 10, 0, 0);
    box(win, '|', '-');
    mvwvline(win, 1, 1, '|', 10); //does not print to screen
    touchwin(win);
    wrefresh(win);

    getchar();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if `win` is guaranteed to return non-`NULL` but check the documentation, because in the case it could return `NULL` you will have undefined behavior.